# Firefox CSS float bug?

Tags: css, firefox, css-float

**UPDATE**
It seems to have magically corrected itself because now it works, but I emphasize that it wasn't a cache issue because even I was able to update with new images but they always appeared "below" rather than "next to"... I don't understand...but suddenly it worked now.

if you check [www.dodomainer.com](http://www.dodomainer.com) in Safari and Chrome, the two images in the header float, but not in Firefox.  Any idea how to fix this?  Note, it's definitely not this way in Firefox as a result of a cache

this is the code that I use. Any idea how to fix the problem?

```
<div class="header a"><a href="http://dodomainer.com/">
<img src="http://dodomainer.com/images/dodo4.jpg" width="400" height="50" padding-left="10px"  alt="dodobird" />
</a></div>

<div class="header b">
<a href="http://dodomainer.com/">
<img src="http://dodomainer.com/images/dodotest.jpg" width="380" height="70" padding-left="10px"  alt="dodobird" />
</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {  
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}

 .a {
    height: 50px;   
}

 .b  {
    height: 70px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}
```

[image: firefox]

Comment: Looks the same to me on FF5. Which version of Firefox are you seeing this?

Comment: @Wesley Murch @Ibu @Paniyar See image in OP of my firefox problem.  I don't know which version I'm using but it's definitely not the latest, because when I try to update it, there's always an error.

Comment: @Michael: Help > About Firefox - will show version number.

Comment: see update in OP. Problem fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem to be fixed here.

Your code should work in all browsers. I checked in IE, FF, Opera (all latest though). All good.

There are just 2 child divs with float:left.

Comment: what version of FF you using? Also do a view source of the page and show us what you see.

Comment: It seems to have magically corrected itself because now it works, but I emphasize that it wasn't a cache issue because even I was able to update with new images but they always appeared "below" rather than "next to"... I don't understand...but suddenly it worked now.

Comment: Looking images are not fitting and overflowing. You can set overflow:hidden to the parent div. Also you can set reduce the image dimension by scaling down. That way you will find if images are too wide to fit. You need 900+ pixels to fit both images including 100 px left padding.

Comment: @Michael:  Nothing is magic.  A program will **always** give the same result for the same input(s).  I think you should try to pick apart **all** of the submitted answers to learn why you have these troubles instead of simply accepting the first band-aide that appears to work.  You have an 800 pixel wide container and two images plus padding that adds up to 800 pixels ... you really have **no room** left for more padding and this explains your cross-browser inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

Michael, i feel like you may have an overflow issue here regarding your padding and the various methods browsers compute the box model. Header A has a width of 400 but an image within of 400+the padding.  Remove the padding or resize it's container to actually contain it.  Other option is to set overflow to hidden

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine in my FF and other browsers.

However, you may want to reduce the `padding` in

```
.b  {
    height: 70px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}
```

That could be causing you problems.

**EDIT:**

The original problem may have disappeared because of `padding-left:10px;` that was added `inline` to the `img`.  If that is removed, you **may** experience the problem again.

Comment: thanks, see update in OP, the problem is fixed now. However, I needed some padding because it was crunched against the left image